# UIStepper and UILabel not displaying in UITableViewCell until the cell is clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, uistepper

I want the Stepper and Label displayed on all rows by default and not only when the row is selected.

Setup:  I have a custom TableViewCell with both a Label and Stepper on a TableViewController.  The label and stepper are working properly and are properly spaced in their container.  I just cannot see either until I click on the row.

Comment: Show your code for `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `- tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StepperTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel!.text = furniture[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

Comment: I didn't implement tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: You'll need to show the code for your UITableViewController and UITableViewCell

Comment: import UIKit

class StepperTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
    
    IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
        countLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}

Comment: class BTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  
    private var furniture: [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        furniture  = ["Armoire", "Queen Size Bed"]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return furniture.count
    }

    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StepperTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = furniture[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }    
}

Comment: @Leonardo Any ideas on how I can resolve this?  Thanks

Comment: Not sure, check the label and stepper position on `setSelected` before you make any changes to them. They may be initialized on the wrong position